# How to create a properly formatted array of gson objects

Tags: android, json, file-io, gson

Everytime someone makes a transaction in my app I would like to save it to local storage using json / gson. I believe I am nearly there but my problem is correctly formatting the json file every time I write to it.

I would like to append to the file every time I create a Transaction object, and then at some point read every Transaction object from the file for display in a list. Here is what I have so far:

```
public void saveTransaction(Transaction transaction)
            throws JSONException, IOException {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(transaction);

        //Write the file to disk
        Writer writer = null;
        try {
            OutputStream out = mContext.openFileOutput(mFilename, Context.MODE_APPEND);
            writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
            writer.write(json);
        } finally {
            if (writer != null)
                writer.close();
        }
    }
```

My transaction object has an amount, a user id and a boolean, writing with this code I can read the following json String:

```
{"mAmount":"12.34","mIsAdd":"true","mUID":"76163164"}
{"mAmount":"56.78","mIsAdd":"true","mUID":"76163164"}
```

I am reading these values like so but can only read the first one (I guess because they are not in an array / properly formatted json object):

```
 public ArrayList<Transaction> loadTransactions() throws IOException, JSONException {

        ArrayList<Transaction> allTransactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            //Open and read the file into a string builder
            InputStream in = mContext.openFileInput(mFilename);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder jsonString = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                //Line breaks are omitted and irrelevant
                jsonString.append(line);
            }

            //Extract every Transaction from the jsonString here -----

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //Ignore this one, happens when launching for the first time
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        }
        return allTransactions;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

im not sure i understand your question, but have you tried creating a TransactionCollection object that has an `ArrayList<Transaction> transactions`

and create your json from the TransactionCollection object instead of each transaction?